# SSRS Visibility Hidden IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False) doesn't work on text boxes

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that enables me to hide column headers using the following:

```
IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)
```

But it doesn't work for text boxes using a similar formula:

```
IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "RPL", True, False)
```

Is there some other step I'm missing to hide text boxes from display on the report server but allow them to display when export to Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive, True, False)
```

Or simply set to:

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive
```